# angular 2 getting error 'Property '_http' does not exist on type' when trying to use injected http provider

Tags: angular

I'm injecting the http provider to my service using the constructor but when trying to use the this._http.get i'm getting an error Property '_http' does not exist on type 'typeof UsersService'

When tring to move the _http to the constructor e.g.

```
constructor(private _http: Http){}
```

i'm getting:
Property '_http' does not exist on type 'typeof UsersService'

bootstrap

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ActionsComponent } from './actions/actions.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DataComponent } from './data/data.component';
import {UsersService} from './users.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/actions', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'actions', component: ActionsComponent },
  { path: 'data', component: DataComponent, },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ActionsComponent,
    DataComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [UsersService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

users service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import {User} from './user';
const usersLocalStorageKey = 'users';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  private static users: User[];
  private static _http: Http;
  constructor() {}


  public static getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    console.log('HI', this._http);
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/users')
      .map((res: Response) => <User[]>res.json());
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need provide injected classes in Providers of Module class.  Add your service in Providers of ngModule

```
@NgModule({declarations: [... ], imports: [... ], providers: [ UsersService ], bootstrap:[.. ]})
```

Inject your http with help of `constructor()` like below,

```
 private static _http: Http;  // remove this line here

 constructor(private _http: Http) {
 }
```

I hope this will solve your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

your constructor() don't set objects,

you could need to do something like constructor(private http: _HttpClient)

Comment: Otherwise, Why you use static for http?